# Create a new column with three string categories in R

Tags: r

So I have health data which I am analysing and I want to add a new column which categorises BMI into underweight, normal weight, and overweight. Below is a sample if the data. The BMI variable is a column.

```
bmi 
21.9671
34.9279
23.507
17.679
43.678
```

what I would like is to make a column called rating  which will take values of bmi <= 18.5 and give a rating of underweight, if the bmi is between 18.5 and 25 then rating should be normal weight otherwise rating will be overweight. What I want the rating column to look like according to the bmi given above is given below.

rating
normal weight
overweight'
normal weight
underweight
overweight.

I tried an if statement but it only takes the first row and applies to the rest of the columns. SO it will give that all BMIs belong in the category "normal weight"

I would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

The `case_when` function from the `dplyr` library is well suited to your requirement:

```r
df$rating <- case_when(
    df$bmi <= 18.5 ~ "underweight",
    df$bmi <= 25 ~ "normal",
    TRUE ~ "overweight"
)
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, that is very helpful, onward with my final project I go. I really appreciate the help.